# cfgrid and cfajaximport mouseover

Tags: coldfusion, cfgrid

I have the following:

```
<cfajaximport/>
<html>

<head>
<script>

myf = function(data,cellmd,record,row,col,store) {
 if(data == "Product 4")
return "<b>" + data + "</b>";       
else  return data;
}
testgrid = function() {
mygrid = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject('data');
ds = mygrid.getDataSource();
cm = mygrid.getColumnModel();
cm.setRenderer(0, Ext.util.Format.usMoney);
cm.setRenderer(1,myf);

}

</script>
</head>

 <body>

<cfset data = queryNew("price,product")>
<cfloop from=1 to=10 index="x">
<cfset total = randRange(20,100) & "." & randRange(1,99)>
<cfset product = "Product #X#">
<cfset queryAddRow(data)>
<cfset querySetCell(data, "price", total+0, x)>
<cfset querySetCell(data, "product", product, x)>
</cfloop>

  <cfform name="test">
  <cfgrid autowidth="true" name="data" format="html" query="data" width="600">
   <cfgridcolumn name="price" header="Price">
   <cfgridcolumn name="product" header="Product">
   </cfgrid>
   </cfform>

   <cfset ajaxOnLoad("testgrid")>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Picked up from Raymond Camden's blog. I need to somehow add a mouseover event to product column to display product details. (like cost).

Any help on how to implement this event?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating html inside the query cell.

```
<cfset product = 

'<a href="##" onMouseOver="javascript:showWin(''dsp_productDetails.cfm?pid='' & Product#x# & '') onMouseOut="javascript:cleanup()">' & Product#x# & '</a>'>
```

Otherwise, you will need to play with extJs.